# PHP MySQL PDO results to recursive associative array?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, iteration

I have a `MySQL` table:

```
+---------+------------------------+-----------+
| topicID | questionTopics_topicID | topicName |
+---------+------------------------+-----------+
|       1 |                      1 | Root      |
|       2 |                      1 | Colors    |
|       3 |                      2 | Black     |
|       4 |                      2 | White     |
|       5 |                      1 | Animals   |
|       6 |                      5 | Dog       |
|       7 |                      5 | Cat       |
+---------+------------------------+-----------+
```

I would like to have a `PHP Array`, where the result set is fetched as `questionTopics_topicID` being the parent:

```
$array = array(
    "Animals" => array(
            6 => "Dog",
            7 => "Cat"
    ),
    "Colors" => array(
        3 => "Black",
        4 => "White"
    ),
);
```

Currently I do it with iterating through 2 times the result set, first adding the `main-categories` (Colors, Animals), then adding the `sub-categories` (Dog, White).

Is there any way of achieving the same end result with `PDO`, without manually iterating?

Comment: If there are only 2 levels, join table to itself and then use grouping from fetchAll example

Comment: You can JOIN the table with itself and get both in one query.  Something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cd914/11